# Help optimizing an SQL Query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am having noticing some performance issues on my MySQL Server. The slow query log is showing four queries which are causing the issue, taking around 10 seconds to run each query. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of running the query.

The table I am selecting from has around 13,000 rows, and is structured like:

```
id  p   year    time            b      o           type
1   dec 10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        cape
2   jan 10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        cape
3   feb 10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        cape
4   q1  10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        cape
5   q2  10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        cape
6   q3  10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        cape
7   q4  10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        cape
8   11  10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        cape
9   12  10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        cape
10  dec 10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        pmx
11  jan 10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        pmx
12  feb 10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        pmx
13  q1  10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        pmx
14  q2  10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        pmx
15  q3  10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        pmx
16  q4  10  2010-12-02 12:34:27 1000    1000        pmx
```

I run four queries - one for each type, which select each p and order by time. This data is displayed on the front end of the website through four tables.

The queries that are slow are:

```
SELECT type,id,p,time,b,o
FROM zz
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM zz AS f
            WHERE f.p = zz.p
            AND type = 'pmx')
AND TYPE = 'pmx';
```

(then the same for three other types)

Does anyone have any tips for improving the actual query?

Thanks

Comment: First of all created indices on type, id columns

Comment: Thanks for this, however I already have indices on these columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  zz.type,
        zz.id,
        zz.p,
        zz.time,
        zz.b,
        zz.o
FROM    zz INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  type,
                    MAX(id) MaxID
            FROM    zz
            WHERE   type IN ('1','2','3','4')
            GROUP BY type
        ) m ON  zz.type = m.type
            AND zz.ID = m.MaxID
```

Where `('1','2','3','4')` are the four types in question.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however this query only returns one row, whereas my query returns severall.

Comment: Thanks again for this. I made a few changes which produces the result I was looking for, and brought the query time down from 10 seconds to 0.2!

SELECT  zz.type,
        zz.id,
        zz.p,
        zz.time,
        zz.b,
        zz.o
FROM    zz
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT p,max(id) AS maxid
            FROM zz
            WHERE type = $TYPE
            GROUP BY p
            ) b
ON zz.p=b.p AND zz.id=b.maxid
WHERE zz.type = $TYPE